# How to import JSON into R and convert it to table?

Tags: json, r, loops, dictionary, rjson

I want to play with data that is now saved in JSON format. But I am very new to R and have little clue of how to play with data. You can see below what I managed to achieve. But first, my code:

```
library(rjson)
json_file <- "C:\\Users\\Saonkfas\\Desktop\\WOWPAPI\\wowpfinaljson.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

I was able to the data:

```
for (x in json_data){print (x)}
```

Although output looks pretty raw:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$wins
[1] "118"

[[1]]$losses
[1] "40"
# And so on
```

Note that the JSON is somewhat nested. I could create tables with Python, but R seems much more complicated.

Edit:

My JSON:

```
{
"play1": [
    {
        "wins": "118",
        "losses": "40",
        "max_killed": "7",
        "battles": "158",
        "plane_id": "4401",
        "max_ground_object_destroyed": "3"
    },
    {
        "wins": "100",
        "losses": "58",
        "max_killed": "7",
        "battles": "158",
        "plane_id": "2401",
        "max_ground_object_destroyed": "3"
    },
    {
        "wins": "120",
        "losses": "38",
        "max_killed": "7",
        "battles": "158",
        "plane_id": "2403",
        "max_ground_object_destroyed": "3"
    }
],

"play2": [
    {
        "wins": "12",
        "losses": "450",
        "max_killed": "7",
        "battles": "158",
        "plane_id": "4401",
        "max_ground_object_destroyed": "3"
    },
    {
        "wins": "150",
        "losses": "8",
        "max_killed": "7",
        "battles": "158",
        "plane_id": "2401",
        "max_ground_object_destroyed": "3"
    },
    {
        "wins": "120",
        "losses": "328",
        "max_killed": "7",
        "battles": "158",
        "plane_id": "2403",
        "max_ground_object_destroyed": "3"
    }
],
```

Comment: Post a portion of your json data. Also, try the RJSONIO package.

Comment: and/or have a look at the ever so slightly newer `rjsonlite` package described here: https://public.opencpu.org/posts/jsonlite-a-smarter-json-encoder/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`fromJSON` returns a list, you can use the `*apply` functions to go through each element.
It's fairly straightforward (once you know what to do!) to convert it to a "table" (data frame is the correct R terminology).

```
library(rjson)

# You can pass directly the filename
my.JSON <- fromJSON(file="test.json")

df <- lapply(my.JSON, function(play) # Loop through each "play"
  {
  # Convert each group to a data frame.
  # This assumes you have 6 elements each time
  data.frame(matrix(unlist(play), ncol=6, byrow=T))
  })

# Now you have a list of data frames, connect them together in
# one single dataframe
df <- do.call(rbind, df)

# Make column names nicer, remove row names
colnames(df) <- names(my.JSON[[1]][[1]])
rownames(df) <- NULL

df
  wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
1  118     40          7     158     4401                           3
2  100     58          7     158     2401                           3
3  120     38          7     158     2403                           3
4   12    450          7     158     4401                           3
5  150      8          7     158     2401                           3
6  120    328          7     158     2403                           3
```

Answer (score 11):

I find `jsonlite` to be a little more user friendly for this task. [Here is a comparison of three JSON parsing packages](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31702_9c22e3d1a0c44968a4a1f9656f1800ab.html) (biased in favor of `jsonlite`)

```
library(jsonlite)
data <- fromJSON('path/to/file.json')

data
#> $play1
#   wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
# 1  118     40          7     158     4401                           3
# 2  100     58          7     158     2401                           3
# 3  120     38          7     158     2403                           3
# 
# $play2
#   wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
# 1   12    450          7     158     4401                           3
# 2  150      8          7     158     2401                           3
# 3  120    328          7     158     2403                           3
```

If you want to collapse those list names into a new column, I recommend `dplyr::bind_rows` rather than `do.call(rbind, data)`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- bind_rows(data, .id = 'play')

# Source: local data frame [6 x 7]

#    play  wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
#   (chr) (chr)  (chr)      (chr)   (chr)    (chr)                       (chr)
# 1 play1   118     40          7     158     4401                           3
# 2 play1   100     58          7     158     2401                           3
# 3 play1   120     38          7     158     2403                           3
# 4 play2    12    450          7     158     4401                           3
# 5 play2   150      8          7     158     2401                           3
# 6 play2   120    328          7     158     2403                           3
```

Beware that the columns may not have the type you expect (notice the columns are all characters since all of the numbers were quoted in the provided JSON data)!

**Edit Nov. 2017:** One approach to type conversion would be to use `mutate_if` to guess the intended type of character columns.

```
data <- mutate_if(data, is.character, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Instead of loading `reshape2` you could use `rbind.pages` from `jsonlite`, which may be able to go into one call with `fromJSON`

Comment: @RichardScriven Neat! I hadn't noticed that function. Though in this case it does something similar in effect to `do.call(rbind, data)` in that it doesn't preserve the play# as a new variable (if that is important to the OP)

Comment: @Eric what is the best way to get the correct column types? If I convert the json file to csv and import to R I get the correct types but importing straight with jsonlite gives me the wrong types.

Comment: @ant unfortunately I can't answer your question without knowing what your data looks like and what types are wrong. Though, it is probably easiest just to convert everything to a data frame and then coerce columns to the desired types if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer **tidyjson** over rjson and jsonlite as it has a easy workflow for converting multilevel nested json objects to 2 dimensional tables. Your problem can be easily solved using this package from github.

```
devtools::install_github("sailthru/tidyjson")

library(tidyjson)
library(dplyr)

> json %>%  as.tbl_json %>% gather_keys %>% gather_array %>%  
+   spread_values(
+     wins = jstring("wins"),
+     losses = jstring("losses"),
+     max_killed = jstring("max_killed"),
+     battles = jstring("battles"),
+     plane_id = jstring("plane_id"),
+     max_ground_object_destroyed = jstring("max_ground_object_destroyed")
+    )
```

## Output

```
  document.id   key array.index wins losses max_killed battles plane_id max_ground_object_destroyed
1           1 play1           1  118     40          7     158     4401                           3
2           1 play1           2  100     58          7     158     2401                           3
3           1 play1           3  120     38          7     158     2403                           3
4           1 play2           1   12    450          7     158     4401                           3
5           1 play2           2  150      8          7     158     2401                           3
6           1 play2           3  120    328          7     158     2403                           3
```

Comment: How is variable `json` defined in your code? In the other examples this is loaded from disk.