# how to read json data and retrieve all the values in the tabular format in R

Tags: r

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"58eb2d682d546d63a0252c1e"},"CookieID":"2202256445201745143942335","RespCode":"201","Dateval":"05042017155753521","urlval":"http://taxguru.in/goods-and-service-tax/sales-tax-forms-demystified.html"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"58eb2d682d546d63a0252c1f"},"CookieID":"493511602017451518184","RespCode":"300","Dateval":"05042017155751163","urlval":"http://taxguru.in/income-tax/understanding-44ab-tax-audit.html"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"58eb2d682d546d63a0252c20"},"CookieID":"201745145852229","RespCode":"300","Dateval":"05042017155750765","urlval":"http://taxguru.in/income-tax/capital-gains-income-sale-agricultural-land.html"}
```

I need to read my json file in R using *rjson* package and get the entries in the form of a table.
I tried following code

```
library(rjson)  
exposure=fromJSON(file="expodata.json")  
expo_data=as.data.frame(exposure)  
# View(expo_data)
```

When I view the data it is showing me only the first row and not the others.
Where am I going wrong.How to get all the rows when I view it.
I am a beginner and struggling to work aroung with this.Can someone help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import JSON into R and convert it to table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925492/how-to-import-json-into-r-and-convert-it-to-table)

Comment: If I use this command library(jsonlite) exposure1=fromJSON(txt="expodata.json") I am getting this error Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: trailing garbage
          tax-forms-demystified.html"} {"_id":{"$oid":"58eb2d682d546d6
                     (right here) ------^

Comment: I am not able to rectify it.what to do