# How to make a table of a large json file in R

Tags: json, r, rstudio

I'm new to R and looking to interprete data from a game API. A friend of mine gave me a large json file with a hundrer game matches in it. I've looked in several solutions ([How to import JSON into R and convert it to table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925492/how-to-import-json-into-r-and-convert-it-to-table)) but can't manage to make a decent table out of my json file.

Is the json file wrong ? Below an excerpt of the json code for 1 match (there are a hundred in the file). How can I convert that into a table ?

```
{"_id":{"$numberLong":"3319501660"},"platformId":"EUW1","gameCreation":{"$numberLong":"1503783552498"},"gameDuration":2799,"queueId":420,"mapId":11,"seasonId":9,"gameVersion":"7.17.200.3955","gameMode":"CLASSIC","gameType":"MATCHED_GAME","teams":[{"teamId":100,"win":"Fail","firstBlood":false,"firstTower":true,"firstInhibitor":false,"firstBaron":true,"firstDragon":true,"firstRiftHerald":false,"towerKills":7,"inhibitorKills":3,"baronKills":2,"dragonKills":3,"vilemawKills":0,"riftHeraldKills":0,"dominionVictoryScore":0,"bans":[{"championId":29,"pickTurn":1},{"championId":117,"pickTurn":2},{"championId":119,"pickTurn":3},{"championId":113,"pickTurn":4},{"championId":57,"pickTurn":5}]},{"teamId":200,"win":"Win","firstBlood":true,"firstTower":false,"firstInhibitor":true,"firstBaron":false,"firstDragon":false,"firstRiftHerald":false,"towerKills":10,"inhibitorKills":4,"baronKills":1,"dragonKills":2,"vilemawKills":0,"riftHeraldKills":0,"dominionVictoryScore":0,"bans":[{"championId":119,"pickTurn":6},{"championId":18,"pickTurn":7},{"championId":61,"pickTurn":8},{"championId":31,"pickTurn":9},{"championId":40,"pickTurn":10}]}],"participants":[{"participantId":1,"teamId":100,"championId":429,"spell1Id":7,"spell2Id":4,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6111,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6121,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6131,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6143,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6151,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6162,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6211,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6223,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6231,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6232,"rank":4},{"masteryId":6243,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5245,"rank":6},{"runeId":5247,"rank":3},{"runeId":5277,"rank":9},{"runeId":5317,"rank":9},{"runeId":5337,"rank":2},{"runeId":5412,"rank":1}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"UNRANKED","stats":{"participantId":1,"win":false,"item0":1038,"item1":1038,"item2":1038,"item3":1038,"item4":1038,"item5":1038,"item6":3363,"kills":17,"deaths":9,"assists":16,"largestKillingSpree":5,"largestMultiKill":3,"killingSprees":5,"longestTimeSpentLiving":449,"doubleKills":2,"tripleKills":1,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":347702,"magicDamageDealt":4920,"physicalDamageDealt":326066,"trueDamageDealt":16716,"largestCriticalStrike":1004,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":60343,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":2391,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":55927,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":2025,"totalHeal":9565,"totalUnitsHealed":4,"damageSelfMitigated":34534,"damageDealtToObjectives":38987,"damageDealtToTurrets":4823,"visionScore":33,"timeCCingOthers":45,"totalDamageTaken":53894,"magicalDamageTaken":14751,"physicalDamageTaken":30989,"trueDamageTaken":8153,"goldEarned":22415,"goldSpent":28275,"turretKills":0,"inhibitorKills":1,"totalMinionsKilled":298,"neutralMinionsKilled":40,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":32,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":0,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":2270,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":1,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":12,"wardsKilled":5,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":true,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":1,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":6.3,"0-10":6.6,"30-end":6.333333333333333,"20-30":6.4},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":466.29999999999995,"0-10":317.0,"30-end":627.8,"20-30":698.5},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":575.2,"0-10":292.5,"30-end":502.40000000000003,"20-30":519.8},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-0.7,"0-10":0.10000000000000009,"30-end":1.133333333333333,"20-30":0.09999999999999987},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":131.84999999999997,"0-10":33.14999999999999,"30-end":14.666666666666666,"20-30":-95.20000000000002},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":700.1,"0-10":300.7,"30-end":1885.3999999999999,"20-30":1195.7},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-249.24999999999997,"0-10":-137.40000000000003,"30-end":336.93333333333334,"20-30":185.04999999999995},"role":"DUO_CARRY","lane":"BOTTOM"}},{"participantId":2,"teamId":100,"championId":64,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":11,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6111,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6121,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6131,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6142,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6312,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6321,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6331,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6341,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6351,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6362,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5245,"rank":9},{"runeId":5290,"rank":6},{"runeId":5296,"rank":3},{"runeId":5316,"rank":9},{"runeId":5337,"rank":1},{"runeId":5347,"rank":2}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"PLATINUM","stats":{"participantId":2,"win":false,"item0":3193,"item1":3190,"item2":1408,"item3":3109,"item4":3111,"item5":3075,"item6":3340,"kills":7,"deaths":10,"assists":17,"largestKillingSpree":2,"largestMultiKill":1,"killingSprees":1,"longestTimeSpentLiving":583,"doubleKills":0,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":168394,"magicDamageDealt":44274,"physicalDamageDealt":109508,"trueDamageDealt":14611,"largestCriticalStrike":37,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":24686,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":6545,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":17836,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":304,"totalHeal":12700,"totalUnitsHealed":1,"damageSelfMitigated":80108,"damageDealtToObjectives":15366,"damageDealtToTurrets":2710,"visionScore":78,"timeCCingOthers":42,"totalDamageTaken":53533,"magicalDamageTaken":11750,"physicalDamageTaken":35077,"trueDamageTaken":6704,"goldEarned":16666,"goldSpent":15850,"turretKills":1,"inhibitorKills":0,"totalMinionsKilled":46,"neutralMinionsKilled":117,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":74,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":0,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":719,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":1,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":34,"wardsKilled":0,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":2,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":0.8,"0-10":0.30000000000000004,"30-end":1.0666666666666667,"20-30":1.8},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":442.3,"0-10":337.4,"30-end":425.2,"20-30":615.3},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":373.5,"0-10":279.9,"30-end":352.93333333333334,"20-30":395.9},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":0.10000000000000009,"0-10":-0.29999999999999993,"30-end":-1.133333333333333,"20-30":0.6000000000000001},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":85.9,"0-10":65.00000000000003,"30-end":-227.46666666666667,"20-30":93.4},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":936.0,"0-10":674.0,"30-end":1357.3333333333333,"20-30":1168.7},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":1.099999999999966,"0-10":112.4,"30-end":-677.0,"20-30":241.40000000000003},"role":"NONE","lane":"JUNGLE"}},{"participantId":3,"teamId":100,"championId":141,"spell1Id":12,"spell2Id":4,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6114,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6122,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6134,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6143,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6312,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6323,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6331,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6332,"rank":4},{"masteryId":6343,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6351,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6362,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5245,"rank":9},{"runeId":5289,"rank":9},{"runeId":5317,"rank":9},{"runeId":5337,"rank":3}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"UNRANKED","stats":{"participantId":3,"win":false,"item0":3142,"item1":3147,"item2":3026,"item3":3742,"item4":3111,"item5":3075,"item6":3364,"kills":7,"deaths":14,"assists":7,"largestKillingSpree":2,"largestMultiKill":1,"killingSprees":1,"longestTimeSpentLiving":395,"doubleKills":0,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":197532,"magicDamageDealt":4075,"physicalDamageDealt":192484,"trueDamageDealt":971,"largestCriticalStrike":31,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":29427,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":2513,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":26752,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":162,"totalHeal":22537,"totalUnitsHealed":1,"damageSelfMitigated":46874,"damageDealtToObjectives":8081,"damageDealtToTurrets":5007,"visionScore":30,"timeCCingOthers":34,"totalDamageTaken":61314,"magicalDamageTaken":20705,"physicalDamageTaken":30877,"trueDamageTaken":9731,"goldEarned":16686,"goldSpent":16025,"turretKills":2,"inhibitorKills":1,"totalMinionsKilled":222,"neutralMinionsKilled":27,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":17,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":2,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":479,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":3,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":7,"wardsKilled":11,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":3,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":7.6,"0-10":5.9,"30-end":2.066666666666667,"20-30":5.3},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":553.9,"0-10":381.70000000000005,"30-end":385.2666666666667,"20-30":620.3},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":423.9,"0-10":250.29999999999998,"30-end":303.8,"20-30":447.9},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-0.10000000000000009,"0-10":-2.1999999999999997,"30-end":-4.6000000000000005,"20-30":-2.1},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":9.699999999999989,"0-10":-131.3,"30-end":-536.7333333333332,"20-30":46.599999999999966},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":950.5,"0-10":522.0,"30-end":1848.5333333333335,"20-30":1419.1999999999998},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-94.79999999999995,"0-10":242.8,"30-end":-244.79999999999995,"20-30":37.69999999999993},"role":"SOLO","lane":"TOP"}},{"participantId":4,"teamId":100,"championId":34,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6114,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6122,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6131,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6143,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6312,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6322,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6332,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6343,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6352,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6362,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5273,"rank":9},{"runeId":5289,"rank":3},{"runeId":5296,"rank":6},{"runeId":5316,"rank":6},{"runeId":5317,"rank":3},{"runeId":5365,"rank":3}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"GOLD","stats":{"participantId":4,"win":false,"item0":3089,"item1":3157,"item2":3040,"item3":3020,"item4":3151,"item5":3027,"item6":3340,"kills":6,"deaths":8,"assists":11,"largestKillingSpree":2,"largestMultiKill":1,"killingSprees":1,"longestTimeSpentLiving":621,"doubleKills":0,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":231652,"magicDamageDealt":218569,"physicalDamageDealt":10233,"trueDamageDealt":2849,"largestCriticalStrike":938,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":29309,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":28250,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":819,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":240,"totalHeal":15564,"totalUnitsHealed":1,"damageSelfMitigated":21137,"damageDealtToObjectives":17110,"damageDealtToTurrets":3794,"visionScore":30,"timeCCingOthers":72,"totalDamageTaken":40924,"magicalDamageTaken":16363,"physicalDamageTaken":17336,"trueDamageTaken":7224,"goldEarned":17455,"goldSpent":17610,"turretKills":2,"inhibitorKills":0,"totalMinionsKilled":282,"neutralMinionsKilled":1,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":0,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":0,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":3661,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":2,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":17,"wardsKilled":4,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":4,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":8.0,"0-10":5.3,"30-end":5.533333333333334,"20-30":6.300000000000001},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":511.2,"0-10":448.5,"30-end":566.3333333333334,"20-30":475.8},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":422.5,"0-10":221.6,"30-end":407.2,"20-30":414.2},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-0.19999999999999973,"0-10":-0.7999999999999998,"30-end":-4.133333333333334,"20-30":-2.4999999999999996},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-69.80000000000001,"0-10":38.60000000000002,"30-end":-350.06666666666666,"20-30":-129.89999999999998},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":701.8,"0-10":300.2,"30-end":1194.8666666666666,"20-30":1001.6999999999999},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":315.9,"0-10":-23.200000000000003,"30-end":105.66666666666652,"20-30":258.2},"role":"SOLO","lane":"MIDDLE"}},{"participantId":5,"teamId":100,"championId":63,"spell1Id":14,"spell2Id":4,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6114,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6123,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6134,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6143,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6154,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6164,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6311,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6322,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6332,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6342,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5273,"rank":9},{"runeId":5289,"rank":9},{"runeId":5315,"rank":5},{"runeId":5316,"rank":4},{"runeId":5357,"rank":3}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"PLATINUM","stats":{"participantId":5,"win":false,"item0":2301,"item1":3157,"item2":3116,"item3":3151,"item4":3190,"item5":3020,"item6":3364,"kills":7,"deaths":9,"assists":15,"largestKillingSpree":2,"largestMultiKill":2,"killingSprees":3,"longestTimeSpentLiving":957,"doubleKills":1,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":135067,"magicDamageDealt":124247,"physicalDamageDealt":7347,"trueDamageDealt":3472,"largestCriticalStrike":0,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":44906,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":41520,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":1338,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":2047,"totalHeal":4154,"totalUnitsHealed":1,"damageSelfMitigated":22302,"damageDealtToObjectives":13109,"damageDealtToTurrets":2036,"visionScore":132,"timeCCingOthers":55,"totalDamageTaken":35260,"magicalDamageTaken":13660,"physicalDamageTaken":20400,"trueDamageTaken":1199,"goldEarned":16871,"goldSpent":16150,"turretKills":0,"inhibitorKills":0,"totalMinionsKilled":74,"neutralMinionsKilled":1,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":1,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":0,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":1130,"champLevel":17,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":7,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":46,"wardsKilled":21,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":true,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":5,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":1.1,"0-10":0.30000000000000004,"30-end":2.6666666666666665,"20-30":1.6},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":444.5,"0-10":247.5,"30-end":582.8666666666667,"20-30":237.89999999999998},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":453.29999999999995,"0-10":197.2,"30-end":428.26666666666665,"20-30":303.7},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-0.7,"0-10":0.10000000000000009,"30-end":1.133333333333333,"20-30":0.09999999999999987},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":131.84999999999997,"0-10":33.14999999999999,"30-end":14.666666666666666,"20-30":-95.20000000000002},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":347.9,"0-10":173.1,"30-end":1167.9333333333334,"20-30":855.4},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-249.24999999999997,"0-10":-137.40000000000003,"30-end":336.93333333333334,"20-30":185.04999999999995},"role":"DUO_SUPPORT","lane":"BOTTOM"}},{"participantId":6,"teamId":200,"championId":79,"spell1Id":11,"spell2Id":4,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6211,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6223,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6231,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6241,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6251,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6262,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6312,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6321,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6331,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6341,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5273,"rank":9},{"runeId":5289,"rank":9},{"runeId":5317,"rank":9},{"runeId":5357,"rank":3}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"PLATINUM","stats":{"participantId":6,"win":true,"item0":1409,"item1":3109,"item2":3075,"item3":3047,"item4":3065,"item5":3025,"item6":3340,"kills":4,"deaths":5,"assists":18,"largestKillingSpree":3,"largestMultiKill":1,"killingSprees":1,"longestTimeSpentLiving":867,"doubleKills":0,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":202509,"magicDamageDealt":141167,"physicalDamageDealt":42311,"trueDamageDealt":19031,"largestCriticalStrike":503,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":21302,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":16045,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":4066,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":1190,"totalHeal":30002,"totalUnitsHealed":1,"damageSelfMitigated":92484,"damageDealtToObjectives":11070,"damageDealtToTurrets":403,"visionScore":80,"timeCCingOthers":55,"totalDamageTaken":61451,"magicalDamageTaken":21362,"physicalDamageTaken":38188,"trueDamageTaken":1900,"goldEarned":16990,"goldSpent":15750,"turretKills":0,"inhibitorKills":1,"totalMinionsKilled":65,"neutralMinionsKilled":93,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":62,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":2,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":1020,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":4,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":37,"wardsKilled":2,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":true,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":6,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":0.7,"0-10":0.6,"30-end":2.2,"20-30":1.2},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":356.4,"0-10":272.4,"30-end":652.6666666666666,"20-30":521.9},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":308.8,"0-10":254.5,"30-end":428.3333333333333,"20-30":371.5},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-0.10000000000000009,"0-10":0.29999999999999993,"30-end":1.133333333333333,"20-30":-0.6000000000000001},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-85.9,"0-10":-65.00000000000003,"30-end":227.46666666666667,"20-30":-93.4},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":934.9000000000001,"0-10":561.6,"30-end":2034.3333333333333,"20-30":927.3},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-1.099999999999966,"0-10":-112.4,"30-end":677.0,"20-30":-241.40000000000003},"role":"NONE","lane":"JUNGLE"}},{"participantId":7,"teamId":200,"championId":12,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":3,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6212,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6223,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6232,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6241,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6251,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6262,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6311,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6322,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6332,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6342,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5273,"rank":9},{"runeId":5290,"rank":9},{"runeId":5316,"rank":9},{"runeId":5347,"rank":3}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"GOLD","stats":{"participantId":7,"win":true,"item0":3111,"item1":2303,"item2":3107,"item3":3190,"item4":3504,"item5":3082,"item6":3364,"kills":0,"deaths":9,"assists":17,"largestKillingSpree":0,"largestMultiKill":0,"killingSprees":0,"longestTimeSpentLiving":398,"doubleKills":0,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":30000,"magicDamageDealt":12144,"physicalDamageDealt":8217,"trueDamageDealt":9638,"largestCriticalStrike":0,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":10343,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":7542,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":1557,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":1243,"totalHeal":19451,"totalUnitsHealed":11,"damageSelfMitigated":87461,"damageDealtToObjectives":1542,"damageDealtToTurrets":736,"visionScore":75,"timeCCingOthers":57,"totalDamageTaken":37370,"magicalDamageTaken":14692,"physicalDamageTaken":22071,"trueDamageTaken":606,"goldEarned":13208,"goldSpent":12350,"turretKills":0,"inhibitorKills":0,"totalMinionsKilled":61,"neutralMinionsKilled":1,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":0,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":1,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":120,"champLevel":17,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":6,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":29,"wardsKilled":14,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":true,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":7,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":1.2,"0-10":1.7000000000000002,"30-end":0.8666666666666667,"20-30":1.8},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":224.0,"0-10":288.0,"30-end":407.3333333333333,"20-30":521.3},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":248.3,"0-10":153.6,"30-end":322.8666666666667,"20-30":333.4},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":0.7,"0-10":-0.10000000000000009,"30-end":-1.133333333333333,"20-30":-0.09999999999999987},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-131.84999999999997,"0-10":-33.14999999999999,"30-end":-14.666666666666666,"20-30":95.20000000000002},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":673.1,"0-10":348.4,"30-end":1267.0666666666668,"20-30":715.5},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":249.24999999999997,"0-10":137.40000000000003,"30-end":-336.93333333333334,"20-30":-185.04999999999995},"role":"DUO_SUPPORT","lane":"BOTTOM"}},{"participantId":8,"teamId":200,"championId":164,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6111,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6121,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6134,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6143,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6151,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6162,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6211,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6223,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6232,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6243,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5245,"rank":9},{"runeId":5290,"rank":9},{"runeId":5317,"rank":9},{"runeId":5335,"rank":3}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"DIAMOND","stats":{"participantId":8,"win":true,"item0":3748,"item1":3078,"item2":3047,"item3":3053,"item4":3065,"item5":3026,"item6":3340,"kills":23,"deaths":7,"assists":8,"largestKillingSpree":7,"largestMultiKill":2,"killingSprees":6,"longestTimeSpentLiving":716,"doubleKills":5,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":352832,"magicDamageDealt":1664,"physicalDamageDealt":304373,"trueDamageDealt":46794,"largestCriticalStrike":0,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":60249,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":1600,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":42302,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":16346,"totalHeal":9560,"totalUnitsHealed":1,"damageSelfMitigated":86901,"damageDealtToObjectives":13385,"damageDealtToTurrets":5562,"visionScore":33,"timeCCingOthers":38,"totalDamageTaken":64401,"magicalDamageTaken":20581,"physicalDamageTaken":42199,"trueDamageTaken":1620,"goldEarned":24699,"goldSpent":25633,"turretKills":2,"inhibitorKills":0,"totalMinionsKilled":339,"neutralMinionsKilled":35,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":15,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":11,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":784,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":0,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":22,"wardsKilled":3,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":8,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":7.7,"0-10":8.1,"30-end":6.666666666666667,"20-30":7.4},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":544.2,"0-10":513.0,"30-end":922.0,"20-30":573.7},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":458.4,"0-10":317.70000000000005,"30-end":686.7333333333332,"20-30":529.7},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":0.10000000000000009,"0-10":2.1999999999999997,"30-end":4.6000000000000005,"20-30":2.1},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-9.699999999999989,"0-10":131.3,"30-end":536.7333333333332,"20-30":-46.599999999999966},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":1045.3,"0-10":279.20000000000005,"30-end":2093.3333333333335,"20-30":1381.5},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":94.79999999999995,"0-10":-242.8,"30-end":244.79999999999995,"20-30":-37.69999999999993},"role":"SOLO","lane":"TOP"}},{"participantId":9,"teamId":200,"championId":202,"spell1Id":7,"spell2Id":4,"masteries":[{"masteryId":6114,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6121,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6134,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6143,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6151,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6161,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6211,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6223,"rank":1},{"masteryId":6232,"rank":5},{"masteryId":6241,"rank":1}],"runes":[{"runeId":5245,"rank":9},{"runeId":5289,"rank":5},{"runeId":5301,"rank":4},{"runeId":5317,"rank":9},{"runeId":5335,"rank":3}],"highestAchievedSeasonTier":"UNRANKED","stats":{"participantId":9,"win":true,"item0":3139,"item1":3087,"item2":3031,"item3":3009,"item4":3094,"item5":3033,"item6":3363,"kills":11,"deaths":15,"assists":18,"largestKillingSpree":4,"largestMultiKill":2,"killingSprees":3,"longestTimeSpentLiving":282,"doubleKills":1,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":334164,"magicDamageDealt":57192,"physicalDamageDealt":274785,"trueDamageDealt":2186,"largestCriticalStrike":2168,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":55957,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":6415,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":48113,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":1428,"totalHeal":12162,"totalUnitsHealed":5,"damageSelfMitigated":18626,"damageDealtToObjectives":8033,"damageDealtToTurrets":5960,"visionScore":61,"timeCCingOthers":22,"totalDamageTaken":40212,"magicalDamageTaken":13586,"physicalDamageTaken":26278,"trueDamageTaken":347,"goldEarned":21161,"goldSpent":22925,"turretKills":4,"inhibitorKills":3,"totalMinionsKilled":293,"neutralMinionsKilled":17,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":9,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":4,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":246,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":1,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":16,"wardsKilled":4,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":true,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0},"timeline":{"participantId":9,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":7.6,"0-10":5.0,"30-end":5.866666666666667,"20-30":6.0},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":423.1,"0-10":210.2,"30-end":774.0,"20-30":605.5},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":361.1,"0-10":202.2,"30-end":560.1333333333333,"20-30":500.1},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":0.7,"0-10":-0.10000000000000009,"30-end":-1.133333333333333,"20-30":-0.09999999999999987},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-131.84999999999997,"0-10":-33.14999999999999,"30-end":-14.666666666666666,"20-30":95.20000000000002},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":873.4,"0-10":400.20000000000005,"30-end":1112.3999999999999,"20-30":965.5},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":249.24999999999997,"0-10":137.40000000000003,"30-end":-336.93333333333334,
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Your json file for 1 match is incomplete or wrong

Comment: I may be incomplete. The character limit for the code paste was 30 000 characters, so I had to cut the code. The code excerpt ends up with ","profileIcon":25}}]}"